# How to recursively get ids from parent/childrens in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have a table of items. Each item has a `parentItemId`. I have an item id and want to get all the item ids from other items where my supplied item id is their parent, but then recursively repeat this downwards. Basically in my mind it looks like a tree, and I start at node x and want to get all the ids of the nodes downwards from x.

How can I achieve this efficiently with a single query in Entity Framework Core?

Note that I only need the ids of each item, not the entire item.

Edit: using MSSQL DB with EF Core 3.1.5

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle, MSSQL etc.,? Mention it along with version

Comment: Sorry, using MSSQL. EF Core V3.1.5.